# Delete row with null value in columnX only when a copy of the record exists

Tags: postgresql, delete-row, isnull

I have the following table:

[image]

and I want to delete records where c3 is null but only when another record with the same values for c1 and c2 already exists. In other words, remove only the row marked with red arrow. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write this as a select, so you don't copy paste and hose something accidentally- you can run it and check that it selects the rows you want to delete

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE 
  t1.c3 IS NULL AND
  EXISTS(
    SELECT null FROM table t2
    WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND COALESCE(t1.c2, 'value that will never appear in the table') = COALESCE(t2.c2, 'value that will never in the table') AND t2.c3 IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Conversion to delete should just be a case of replacing the select * with a delete, but Do comment if it doesn't work out..

Edit remarks:

Used coalesce to demo how to make sure that a c2 value of null on row X is equivalent to another c2 value of null on row Y. It is important that the string you choose for 'value that will never appear in the table' is identical in both occurrences within the sql, and that it can never appear in the table, otherwise rows with nulls will match up with other rows that have actual values

Comment: I think that's it! Thank you very much.

Comment: I run this for the actual table. There is at least one case that this doesn't work. :( For example if I have two records ('B',null,'15'), ('B', null,null). The code will not return ('B', null,null). Is there a fix for this other than removing c2 from subquery? I have 12 columns and any of them can have null value.

Comment: Technically null is never equal to anything else, not even another null, but if you're making. A business logic decision that a null on c2 is the same as another row also with null so log as the c1 are the same then you can use coalesce to convert your null into an equatable value. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate

Comment: Thank you for the extra information and explanation!